# Can't click in inputs in Firefox

Tags: php, html, css, forms, input

I have a form here and for some reason in Firefox I cannot click inside the inputs - works fine in any other browser. Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Thanks

```
<form method="post" id="adduser" class="user-forms" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">



                <p class="form-username">
                    <label for="user_name"><?php _e('Username (required)', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                    <input class="text-input" name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo esc_html( $_POST['user_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
                </p><!-- .form-username -->

 <p class="last_name">
                    <label for="first_name"><?php _e('First Name', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                    <input class="text-input" name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo esc_html( $_POST['first_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
                </p><!-- .last_name -->
                <p class="last_name">
                    <label for="last_name"><?php _e('Last Name', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                    <input class="text-input" name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo esc_html( $_POST['last_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
                </p><!-- .last_name -->



                <p class="form-email">
                    <label for="email"><?php _e('E-mail (required)', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                    <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo esc_html( $_POST['email'], 1 ); ?>" />
                </p><!-- .form-email -->



            </form>
```

Comment: As far as I can see it, the HTML is missing a closing bracket for all `input` fields. Maybe try correcting this first? Or in the short form `<input class="..." ... />`

Comment: You have some extra closing tags: div and p

Comment: Indent your code and you should see something's wrong.

Comment: @DaDaDom This is what is rendered in the browser - the input fields do have a closing tag in my code.

Comment: Why would you copy here what's rendered in the browser? Copy your **actual** code.

Comment: Run your code through validator.w3.org, and you will see that you have several (I think 30) HTML errors on your page. Chances are that one of them is breaking it.

Comment: @F4r-20 I thought that maybe Firefox is rendering something wrong, thats why I posted that - have edited question with original code now.  Thanks

Comment: What is closing div before form? I could not find opening div. Please confirm if you have valid opening/closing tags.

Comment: What version of Firefox? I created a fiddle with your code (http://jsfiddle.net/uzyJt/) and it works for me in Firefox 21, despite the extra </p> & </div>

Comment: Firefox 20 on my machine (Xubuntu) and the latest Firefox on my clients Mac.

Comment: Interestingly, the field does get keyboard focus; you just can't see it.  After clicking on the username field and typing something, running `document.getElementById('user_name').value` in the FireBug console will show what you have typed.  Not sure whether the any of the HTML errors will cause this; normally browsers recover from such things by making best-guesses.

Comment: Incidentally, looking at your code, you appear to be (sometimes) rendering the page as a direct response to a `POST` request.  Consider using [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your padding rule here is causing the problem (line 69):

```
.style-profile textarea, .style-profile input[type="text"] {
    padding: 17px !important;
}
```

Because the input has a fixed height, that rule is really closing out the clickable area, confusing Firefox.

Comment: Cool. I was going to add that perhaps you could use something like `padding: 5px` and remove the height on the input to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

On `line 7` you should remove the entire line, it reads:

```
<center><a href="http://style-card.co.uk/id" border="0"><img src="http://style-card.co.uk/id/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/sclogo.jpg" border="0"></center>
```

You should move the opening form tag from `line 142` to `line 153` this should fix your issues

Comment: Thanks however moving the form opening tag didnt make any difference, and removing line 7 removes the logo from the site.

Comment: You could do with moving logo code from the `head` in to the `header` tags